# How do I turn off Redshift in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, redshift

I installed redshift on my Ubuntu 16.04.

I just type in the terminal `redshift` to enable, but when I want to stop it, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and it turns off for 1 second and comes back again.

So, how do I stop it?

Answer (score 4):

`redshift` is the part of the program that does the work, `redshift-gtk` is the GUI front end that makes it easier to use (disable, postpone etc) from your GUI providing a icon menu on your panel on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt install redshift-gtk
```

which should add the GUI features to your desktop.

As for killing redshift; I'd be lazy and just
`killall redshift`
though you may want to check it’s running in that way using `ps -elf | grep redshift` and adjust for your setup. The command as listed worked on my Ubuntu box.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04 it's just

```
redshift -x
```

Comment: for me this only works for a few seconds